# running a loop with selenium throws an error after the first iteration

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, pycharm

I'm using selenium in python to run through a list of URLS in a CSV file and pull data from each of them.

It works great the first time through the loop, and then the second time, it throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'Chrome'
```

[scraper code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n70sV.png)

Anyone know what I'm getting wrong here?  Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Ari

Comment: don't post code as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to initiate browser only once before reading CSV file. Then, in each iteration, use `driver.get(url)` to navigate to `url`, something like below,

```
1) All your imports
2) Initiate chrome (driver, chrome options, etc)
3) read CSV
4) driver.get(url) & rest of your selenium operation for each iteration
```